# How to repeat Header of an ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, msbi

I have a problem with particular report. I have created as simple matrix report in `SSRS` which user will download in excel format. **I have set header repeat property for the matrix, but when I download the report and check report in print preview, it shows heading of column in first page only after that it is not showing the headers of column.** please advice if any idea to make it happen??

I have already tried the repeat properties of matrix. I guess the issue is with excel format plz advice if you have any solution for same.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Click on Advanced mode (available on column grouping)
   [image]
2. in RowGroups section you will find "(static)" and "(Details)". click on static and press F4
3. Set property values like "Keep With Group" as "After" , "Repeat On New Page" as "True"

4 Go back to table, Right click on row header, Go to tablix properties.

5 heck on "repeat Header Column on each page" and "repeat Header column on each Rows"

I hope this will help you to achieve this functionality...

Comment: hi Naveen thanks for your help, but mu problem is my client needs report in print format, it is working while it is in simple worksheet but it will not work if you view the document in Print preview. any way thanks for your help and time you provided to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Could be bug in KeepTogether property.  Refer to [FIX: KeepTogether property does not work when you generate a report that contains a tablix in SSRS 2008 R2 or in SSRS 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2737499).

**Symptoms**

Consider the following scenario: 
•You have a report that contains a tablix in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services (SSRS 2008 R2) or in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS 2012). The tablix contains a row group. 
•You set the KeepTogether property to "True" and the KeepWithGroup property to "Before." 
•The tablix contains a group footer. 
•You try to generate the report.

In this scenario, the group is not displayed on one page. This behavior occurs because the KeepTogether property does not work correctly.

Note This issue also occurs in versions of SQL Server that were released before SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Resolution**

Cumulative update information

Cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 1. For more information about how to obtain this cumulative update package for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2765331

Cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1Note Because the builds are cumulative, each new fix release contains all the hotfixes and all the security fixes that were included with the previous SQL Server 2012 fix release. We recommend that you consider applying the most recent fix release that contains this hotfix. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2772858

The SQL Server 2012 builds that were released after SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 was released
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2
The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 3. For more information about how to obtain this cumulative update package for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2754552

Cumulative update package 3 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 Note Because the builds are cumulative, each new fix release contains all the hotfixes and all the security fixes that were included with the previous SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 fix release. We recommend that you consider applying the most recent fix release that contains this hotfix. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2730301

The SQL Server 2008 R2 builds that were released after SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 was released 
SQL Server 2012
The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 4. For more information about how to obtain this cumulative update package for SQL Server 2012, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2758687

Cumulative update package 4 for SQL Server 2012 Note Because the builds are cumulative, each new fix release contains all the hotfixes and all the security fixes that were included with the previous SQL Server 2012 fix release. We recommend that you consider applying the most recent fix release that contains this hotfix. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2692828

The SQL Server 2012 builds that were released after SQL Server 2012 was released 
SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 8. For more information about how to obtain this cumulative update package for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2723743

Cumulative update package 8 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1Note Because the builds are cumulative, each new fix release contains all the hotfixes and all the security fixes that were included with the previous SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 fix release. We recommend that you consider applying the most recent fix release that contains this hotfix. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2567616

The SQL Server 2008 R2 builds that were released after SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 was released

**Applies to**

•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services
•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer
•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard
•Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Web
•Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Developer
•Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise
•Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Standard
•Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Web

Answer (score 0):

In excel pages are not there. You would have once sheet per page break. So, on all the sheets headers should be displayed. You have to set the static header property values described by Naveen kumar above.